# Friendly URL for customer portal login page

Tags: customer-portal, mydomain, custom-url

I have a client (call them Acme Foundation) who is using the customer portal.  They would like to set up a friendly URL -- portal.acme.org -- for the portal login.  I have some questions below:

- I presume they would need to go to their DNS registrar and set up subdomain for portal.acme.org?
- What should this subdomain point to in Salesforce?  Their Salesforce My Domain is acme.my.salesforce.com.  Do I need to set up a Domain named "portal.acme.org" and use a Custom URL to tie it a Site?  Does the DNS subdomain point to the salesforce Domain or to the Salesforce Site URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would URL forward the portal.acme.org to the URL for the Customer Portal sites Login URL that you set up.

Information on setting up the Login URL is found here:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_enabling_features_settings.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're referring to by "URL forward" - do you mean at the DNS level or in Salesforce Setup > Domain Management > Custom URLs?

Comment: @DavidCheng - DNS Level